# Why no warning when dynamic abstract is used?

Tags: delphi, dynamic, compiler-warnings, abstract

I have:

```
unit AnimalClasses;

interface

type
  TAnimal = class
  public
    function GetName: string; virtual; abstract;
  end;

type
  TCat = class(TAnimal)
  end;

function AnimalFactory(const ANumber: integer): TAnimal;

implementation

function AnimalFactory(const ANumber: integer): TAnimal;
begin
  Result := TCat.Create;
end;

end.
```

and the compiler gives me the warning:

> [dcc32 Error] AnimalClasses.pas(29): E1020 Constructing instance of 'TCat' containing abstract method 'TAnimal.GetName'

Sadly, when I use `dynamic; abstract;` the compiler does not issue me a warning and then I get a runtime error. Why?

Comment: It is a bug. There should be a warning.

Comment: Thankfully there is no reason ever to use `dynamic`

Comment: I can confirm this issue can be reproduced with D7.